# Converting list of dict to rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame looks as follows

```
df1 = df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[[{"x":0,"y":4}], None, [{"x":10,"y":5}], None], 
                     "b":[5, 6, 7, 8]})
```

How can create a seperate column of x and y from it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
df[['x', 'y']] = df['a'].str[0].apply(pd.Series)

print(df)

                     a  b     x    y
0   [{'x': 0, 'y': 4}]  5   0.0  4.0
1                 None  6   NaN  NaN
2  [{'x': 10, 'y': 5}]  7  10.0  5.0
3                 None  8   NaN  NaN
```